# Opposite of feminist

Tags: single-word-requests

Hopefully no one gets offended by the title but I had a discussion with a coworker whether or not there is a good word for people who fight for men's rights.
If feminists are woman activists, what is the correct term for male activists (really just looking for the word, not for a discussion about activism)
Andronists?

Enlighten us :)

Comment: It's called human rights. We are all people, we are all human beings.

Comment: Can you name a single organization that fights for "men's rights"? If you can, go to their website. You might find the term there. Consider starting in the fashion industry with male models. They are routinely paid less than their female counterparts. Maybe they have a union or something.

Comment: Men have patriarchal power or are in power, as it were. You don't fight for rights if you dominate the scene. Not everything has two sides or is symmetrical. Why should there even be a word for that since the reality does not exist? Except maybe in science fiction.

Comment: @Lambie I understand your point, but everyone nowadays is "a victim.."

Comment: @Karlomanio I dunno, there are difficulties with these issues, hierarchical, historical and hermeneutical. Gosh, that came out unintentionally but seems to express what I'm trying to say....

Comment: If you don't want the title to cause offense or controversy, maybe you shouldn't use a vague word like "opposite" in conjuncition with a politically charged word like "feminist". It's not obvious that "opposite of feminist" means the same thing as "people who fight for men's rights" (it would also be understandable to interpret "opposite of feminist" as "people who fight against women's rights"), and people often post answers just based on the title of a question (it's not good, but they still do it), so you should make sure that your title is not misleading or unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term is ***[masculinist or masculist](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/masculinist)***:

> An advocate of the rights or needs of men.

and they refer to ***[Men's rights movement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Men%27s_rights_movement)***:

> The men's rights movement (MRM) is a part of the larger men's movement. ***It branched off from the men's liberation movement in the early 1970s***.
>
> ***The men's rights movement is made up of a variety of groups and individuals who focus on numerous social issues*** (including family law, parenting, reproduction, domestic violence, circumcision ) and government services (including education, compulsory military service, social safety nets, and health policies), which men's rights advocates say discriminate against men.
>
> ***Masculinities scholar Jonathan A. Allan*** described the men's rights movement as a reactive movement that is defined by its opposition to women and feminism but that has not yet formulated its own theories and methodologies outside of antifeminism.
>
> ***Scholars have described the men's rights movement or parts of the movement to be a backlash to feminism.***

(Wikipedia)

Answer (score -1):

One value-neutral term that is used is [***masculist***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masculism) or ***masculinist*** -- they're used pretty interchangeably.

Lots of people all over the spectrum prefer to use more loaded terms, from *chauvinist*/*mysoginist* to *anti-feminist* or *red-piller.* So if the movement is around long enough, you have to wonder whether the standard term for it will be one like the word I suggested above, or one of these loaded terms that gets co-opted (the way that, e.g., *queer* or *gay* have come to be pretty close to neutral, and often feel more appropriate than the objective *homosexual*).

Comment: None of those is about rights.

Comment: Sure they are, every bit as much as *feminist* is. The Wikipedia entry for *masculism* begins: `Masculism or masculinism may variously refer to advocacy of the rights or needs of men and boys.` OED defines the term as `advocacy of the rights of men.`

Comment: I don't mind being voted down (too much), but I feel as if I was voted down for purely emotional and not logical reasons.  I was looking for an objective antonym of feminism, which is different from devoting oneself's to rights.  For me, you can be a feminist without being an activist.  A traditionalist is one who advocates for so-called traditional role models and could be considered an activist.  Men's rights' activists when it comes to divorce is NOT the antonym of Feminists.

Comment: @Karlomanio - I didn't downvote you, fwiw. I haven't voted anyone down on this question/thread. I assume I've gotten downvoted by the same people as you -- seems they're just hitting everyone on this thread. Constructive.

Comment: @spoko I agree with you.  This is only about meaning of a word.  It is not a personal attack.  We need to be able to discuss these things and not be discouraged from doing as such.

Answer (score -1):

Traditionalist is the word I've seen most commonly used to be the opposite of Feminist.  I've never heard the word "Patriarchist", but I believe it would serve as the opposite as well since it would imply a person who believes in patriarchy.

Comment: A traditionalist could indeed be perceived as an activist.  On the other hand, I'm not sure the question is appropriate in interpreting a feminist as an activist.  It would seem the answer would someone in favor of patriarchy.  Some who is in favor of men's rights in a divorce is not really what is the antonym of feminism.